# My co-worker deleted /usr/bin by mistake

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, data-recovery

I know it is my fault to authorize him as a superuser, and I don't have enough knowledge about CentOS 7.

As I wrote in the title, our VPS which runs CentOS 7 lost `/usr/bin` by mistake. And the server doesn't respond to `ping` even using its IPv4 address. Unable to access the server in the ways I know, SSH, FTP, HTTPS, SMTP, IMAP.

Are there any ways to fix this problem?

I can create a new instance, but I don't want to lose the data, especially mailboxes, MySQL stored data, web content.

Comment: Restore from backup.

Comment: Does your VPS host allow you to access the old VPS’s storage from a new VPS?

Comment: @Panki, thank you. I have no recent backup.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thank you, I'll ask it to the hosting company.

Comment: Ask your hosting company to put a rescue CD so that you can extract your data and then just create a new server and migrate the data to it

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any ways to fix this problem?

No, there is nothing we can do.
However, there are some options for you:

1. Restore from backup (this is easy **if** you have one, if not, next time you know better)
2. Get support from your provider to ...

   - get access to the storage from a new VPS
   - let your provider access and backup your files for you

Comment: Thank you. I have no recent backup.
I'll ask them to my provider.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on RHEL8.6 (advice: never work when you are tired) and tried these high level steps:

1. Launch the systems in rescue mode
2. Launch rescue mode from a bootable USB

Both would not work because there was no shell program on the machine

"solved" with these steps:

3. Created a bootable ubuntu drive
4. Booted from the USB drive
5. Mounted the partition belonging to my self-sabotaged installation
6. Recovered some files I wanted to recover
7. Installed from ground zero